# Retrieve theme colors array inside Javascsipt

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, color-palette

I am looking for a way to retrieve the array of color objects you can set in the theme using `add_theme_support('editor-color-palette', [...]);`

Somehow I cannot find any information in the documentation on how to retrieve the theme colors inside a custom block.

```
<ColorPalette
    onChange={ value => onChange(index, 'color', value) }
/>
```

I need the array of colors inside the `onChange` callback to convert a hex color to the slug color name I have set inside php using the function `getColorObjectByColorValue(themeColorsArray, callbackValueHexColor)`.

Answer (score 5):

Just for future readers, thanks for the answer @tobiasegli

```
 <ColorPalette
    colors={wp.data.select( "core/editor" ).getEditorSettings().colors }
    label={'bg color'}
    value={ color }
    onChange={ ( color ) => setState( { color } ) }
    />
```